# Highlight text on focus - kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, angular-directive, kendo-combobox

I am using kendo-combobox in my application.

The requirement is that onclick the value in inputs should get selected so that the user can directly type instead of clearing out manually.

I am using `(focus)="selectValue($event)"` to get the focus. Now in `"selectValue($event)"` I tried many ways to get the value selected.

This is not achievable by `.select()`, `document.getElementById('myInput')`, `element.classList.select('.k-input');`

All these implementations work well with input tags, not working well with kendo.

This below way can somewhat achieve this, but I am still not able to select the value. `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.k-input').select();`

Focus is achievable but the value should get selected as soon as focus is received.

HTML:

```
<kendo-combobox #test formControlName="region"
                                    [data]="regionOptions"
                                    [textField]="'displayName'"
                                    [valueField]="'id'"
                                    [virtual]="virtual"
                                    [filterable]="true"
                                    [kendoDropDownFilter]="{ operator: 'contains' }"
                                    (selectionChange)="regionSelectionChange($event)"
                                    (valueChange)="regionValueChange($event)"
                                    (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
                                    (focus)="selectValue()">
                    </kendo-combobox>
```

JS Code -

```
 selectValue() {
    //this.myInput.select();
    console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
    //console.log($event);
    //this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.k-input').combobox.input.select();
    //his.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').select();
    // this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.k-input').forEach(element => {
    //   console.log(element.value);
      //element.classList.select('.k-input');
      //element.value;
      // let test = element.getElementById('.k-input');
      // console.log(test);
    //});
  }
```

The commented versions are my trials till now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directive like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectOnFocus]'
})
export class SelectOnFocusDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onFocus() {
    const el = this.el.nativeElement;
    if (el.type !== 'text' && el.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA') {
      return;
    }
    el.select();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your component:

```js
// import { ComboBoxComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
@ViewChild('test', { static: true }) test: ComboBoxComponent;

selectValue(): void {
    const nativeElement = this.test.wrapper.nativeElement;
    if (nativeElement) {
        const input = nativeElement.querySelector('input');
        if (input) {
            input.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what you're doing is creating a view child to reference the element defined in the template. Then in the `focus` event handler (named `selectValue`), you're getting the nativeElement, querying for the input, and then calling `select` on the input.

Comment: It seems as though "wrapper" is now a protected property so I am unable to access it. Is there another way to accomplish this?